# Elastic Search query_string on multi field for building a character ngrams search

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search, querydsl

I am new to elasticsearch and I'm trying to solve a few problems with one query.
In the query below I am trying to implement character-ngram based elasticsearch query which would take care of spell-correction as well.

- Sort Options are according to language preferences set by users.
- In query the words "hello there" have been broken down into character ngrams of size 3-5 and the tags themselves
- The fuzziness query was not working as per what I expected so I dropped it.
- "type" are the different media types the results are indexed with. Also requested in the query hence the type filter

My query is as follows -

```
{
    "from": 0, 
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "or": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "type": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                        "tags^10", 
                        "edge_ngrams^5",
                        "ngram5^3", 
                        "ngram4^2", 
                        "ngram3"
                    ], 
                    "query": "hello there hel ell llo hell ello the her ere ther here"
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "size": 20, 
    "sort": [
        "_score", 
        {
            "english": "desc"
        }, 
        {
            "hindi": "desc"
        }, 
        {
            "global": "desc"
        },      
        {
            "popularity": "desc"
        }
    ]    
}
```

The query (I think) works well when I query about a single word like "hello" and ngrams but not so much if i use a phrase "hello there" and ngrams the results are more biased towards one word and results which contain both words don't float up.

Looking forward.